# Second submit with modal in PHP form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form with a submit button that saves the contents of the form. However I have another button that shows a modal. I am looking at passing a variable to a PHP function with the following in the HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="" name="chFrm" id="chFrm">
  <a onclick="showModal(<? echo $channelId ?>);">Preview Content</a>
</form>
```

Then with the javascript:

```
function showModal(data) {

  $.post( "displayEdit.php",
         { action: "getChannelId" },
         function(returnedData){
    console.log(returnedData);
  }).fail(function(){
    console.log("error");
  });

  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='block';
}
```

However, the ajax post does not fire the following function in the PHP script:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == "getChannelId") {
  echo "test";
}
```

Is there another/ best way to do this?

Comment: most likely because of the typo you made `$POST`. You missed the underscore. `$_POST`.

Comment: and make sure short tags are enabled for `<?`. check your console and use error reporting

Comment: `_$POST` is still a typo

Comment: Sorry - there was typos in the question. I have also just tried using                         <a href="javascript:document.chFrm.submit()">Save Changes</a>
then using document.chFrm.command.value = "getChannelId";
        document.chFrm.submit(); but it reloads the page on submit

Comment: In the ajax options... Try `cache:false` and also empty your browser cache.

Comment: Would the ajax post need to be called by the form submit though? Can it be called separately?

Comment: tried the options above and still no luck :(

Comment: No, usually, the use or Ajax is to replace a form "normal" submit, which reloads the whole page.

Comment: Could you try the addition of some single quote around the PHP variable ? `<a onclick="showModal('<?php echo $channelId; ?>');">` And use `<?php`.

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)